# Monte Carlo Simulation in Excel for Non-normal Distributions

Tags: excel, simulation, montecarlo

I would like to simulate the performance a baseball player.  I know his expected performance for every future year and the standard deviations of those performances (based on regression analysis).  At first, I was thinking of using the NORMINV(RAND(),REF,REF) function in excel, but the underlying distribution of baseball players' performances is dramatically right skewed.  Is there a way that I can perform this sort of analysis in Excel or some other free or low-cost software?  The end-goal here is for the simulation to use the right skewed distribution.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Have you looked at a histogram of your regression residuals?  You might be able to pick a strong contender for the distribution from some of the popular skewed distributions, such chi-squared, exponential, gamma, log-normal, etc.  Since residuals are centered at zero, you might need to do some shifting...

Answer (score 1):

R has lots of tools to do this sort of analysis, though you'd have to look through the docs to figure out how to use it.  R is free, at least for non-commercial use.

Comment: R is licensed under the GPL, so it should be free for commercial use too. You might also want to link to http://www.r-project.org/, although, surprisingly, it turns out the [searching Google for "R"](http://www.google.com/search?q=R) _does_ actually return that page as one of the first results.

Comment: Thanks, Joel.  I don't have any experience with R.  I am a VBA/SQL guy.  You think it's reasonably intuitive or does it take a significant investment of time and energy just to look single-variate non-normal data?

Comment: For a script programmer the language isn't too bad, but the math can be hard no matter what language you use.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a cumulative distribution table (that is evenly spaced and sufficiently detailed) then you can easily generate random values from this distribution in Excel by looking up a uniform random number generated by `RAND()` in your distribution table and take the corresponding "x-axis" value.

```
=OFFSET($A$1,MATCH(RAND(),$B$2:$B$102),0)
```

A1 is the cell just above the table of "x-axis" values.
B2:B102 is the cumulative distribution table.

This is a simplified example. Some small modifications may be needed to handle edge-cases and adjust for biases.

If you have enough empirical data you should be able to create the cumulative distribution table.